# Android activity timeout

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

In my application, I am getting an activity timeout in a event listener of a button. Here is the code of the onclick event listener. When I press the button activity is timed out.

```
btn_process_job.setOnClickListener(m2AddListener);
private OnClickListener m2AddListener = new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras !=null) {
            String fileName = extras.getString("file_name");
        }
    }
};
```

The parameters are set in another activity as

```
Intent i = new Intent(CameraPreview.this, InitProgram.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.putExtra("file_name", mLocation.getName());
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: can you be more specific about your issue?

Comment: @Agarwal My application is crashing when I call the on button click event (first code). I used cat log and it is saying the application is timed out for the code.

Comment: @Agarwal I updated my code. the m2Addlistener is failing. It is saying activity time out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
btn_process_job.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras !=null) {
            String fileName = extras.getString("file_name");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi whats the difference between them? they are logically same is not?

Comment: Hi, I restarted my phone and it looks like problem solved. Thanks for the effort.